# AWS RDS Connection Denied Because Hostname

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

So I am attempting to use MySQL workbench to connect to a database in the cloud on AWS RDS services.

When I attempt to connect I get an error like this.

`Access denied for user 'admin'@'ip_octet1-octet2-octet3-octet4.res.spectrum.com' to database 'default_database'`

I have the database set as publicly accessible and all IPS are able to connect. The problem seems to be my client is attempting to try to connect via hostname. I have tried multiple different clients, so it seems to be an issue with AWS or my ISP. I have been able to shell into MySQL instance from other EC2 instances.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: what are you specifying in mysql workbench as the hostname?  an IP or the hostname from the RDS console?

Comment: I have tried both. Yields the same result.

Comment: can you telnet into your MySQL database on the MySQL port?  that will at least verify that it's some sort of IP/routing issue if you are not able to telnet... if you are able to telnet, then it's some sort of credential issue at that point

Comment: Had no idea I could telnet into a mysql db. I will attempt this.

Answer (score 1):

Your mysql user permissions should allow connecting from the particular host. you can grant permission to the existing user as below.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'admin'@'ip_octet1-octet2-octet3-octet4.res.spectrum.com';
```

Reference:
[Create and Grant Mysql Permissions](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-mysql-user-accounts-and-grant-privileges/#:%7E:text=typing%3A%20sudo%20mysql-,Create%20a%20new%20MySQL%20User%20Account,user_password%20with%20the%20user%20password.)

Comment: I was trying to work my around this because this requires me to shell into another EC2 instance to get root privileges to run this command for access to all databases. I am almost convinced amazon designed it this way to bumb up their EC2 utilization across the board. Shell into EC2 to connect to another EC2. When the database is first provisioned I can connect directly, the hostname restriction happens later, a considerable time creating the database (20 min?). I am guessing there are some reverse DNS gremlins on the AWS side.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you are getting, this doesn't seem to be an issue with reaching the server, as the message complains about an access denied, otherwise it would state it can't reach the host. I would go for the password route, as the admin user should get created with '%' for host. Was it a snapshot? Or created from scratch? If so, was the password properly set? If it is from scratch, you can always delete it and create it again.
Regards!